# Fragment Unit Testing: launchFragment throws ClassCastException

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-fragments, testing, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to call methods within my Fragment class in my unit test but I keep getting the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$EmptyFragmentActivity cannot be cast to com.nu.rms.inspections.ui.activity.InspectionActivity`

I'm following Google's [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing). I'm confused why the empty fragment activity is having a cast attempted to become my InspectionActivity (the parent activity the fragment resides in), perhaps this is expected?

What can I do to alleviate the CastClassException and use my fragment's methods within my unit test? ([related question that doesn't solve my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56237797/espresso-test-fail))

**Test**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun `inspection failure point to location mapping is correct`() {
        val scenario = launchFragment<ContentFragment>()
        scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
            //TODO: test logic
        }
    }
...
}
```

**Fragment Class**

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
...
class ContentFragment : Fragment() {...}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$EmptyFragmentActivity cannot be cast to com.nu.rms.inspections.ui.activity.InspectionActivity
    at com.nu.rms.inspections.ui.fragment.ContentFragment.clearRFIDCache(ContentFragment.kt:565)
    at com.nu.rms.inspections.ui.fragment.ContentFragment.showStep1(ContentFragment.kt:222)
    at com.nu.rms.inspections.ui.fragment.ContentFragment.access$showStep1(ContentFragment.kt:37)
    at com.nu.rms.inspections.ui.fragment.ContentFragment$onViewCreated$1.onChanged(ContentFragment.kt:77)
    at com.nu.rms.inspections.ui.fragment.ContentFragment$onViewCreated$1.onChanged(ContentFragment.kt:37)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:113)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:131)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:289)
    at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:33)
    at androidx.lifecycle.Transformations$2$1.onChanged(Transformations.java:153)
    at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.onChanged(MediatorLiveData.java:152)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:113)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:126)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:424)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(LiveData.java:214)
    at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.plug(MediatorLiveData.java:141)
    at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData.addSource(MediatorLiveData.java:96)
    at androidx.lifecycle.Transformations$2.onChanged(Transformations.java:150)
    at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.onChanged(MediatorLiveData.java:152)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:113)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:126)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:424)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(LiveData.java:214)
    at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.plug(MediatorLiveData.java:141)
    at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData.onActive(MediatorLiveData.java:118)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:418)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged(LiveData.java:376)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:300)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:339)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:145)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:131)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.java:51)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2639)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:915)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:293)
    at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$1.perform(FragmentScenario.java:312)
    at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$1.perform(FragmentScenario.java:291)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.lambda$onActivity$1$ActivityScenario(ActivityScenario.java:534)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.robolectric.android.fakes.RoboMonitoringInstrumentation.runOnMainSync(RoboMonitoringInstrumentation.java:53)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.onActivity(ActivityScenario.java:527)
    at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.internalLaunch(FragmentScenario.java:290)
    at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.launch(FragmentScenario.java:203)
    at com.nu.rms.inspections.ExampleUnitTest.inspection failure point to location mapping is correct(ExampleUnitTest.kt:56)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:600)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:260)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:130)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`FragmentScenario` adds your Fragment to an empty activity class - the `androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$EmptyFragmentActivity` mentioned in the stack trace.

That means that your Fragment is **not** in an instance of your `InspectionActivity` class.  You're getting a crash because your `clearRFIDCache()` method is casting the activity to `InspectionActivity`.

If you want to need to test your Fragment within a specific instance of Activity and have a strong coupling between the two, you need to use `ActivityScenario` and manually add your Fragment to that Activity, rather than using `FragmentScenario` that gives you no control over the activity class you're using.

Ideally, you **shouldn't** tightly couple your Fragment to your Activity. For example, you can provide a `FragmentFactory` that uses constructor injection to add the interface your Fragment requires, rather than your Fragment reaching up to the Activity to call methods directly as discussed in the [Fragments: Past, Present, and Future talk](https://youtu.be/RS1IACnZLy4?t=348):

```
// Create an interface for what methods you want to expose
interface Inspector {
  // whatever methods you want
}

// Change your Fragment to take in that interface
class ContentFragment(val inspector: Inspector) : Fragment() {
    fun clearRFIDCache() {
        // Now you can call methods on inspector here
        // without casting your Activity
    }
}

private class InspectionActivityFactory(
    inspector: Inspector
) : FragmentFactory() {
    override fun instantiate(
        classLoader: ClassLoader,
        className: String
    ) = when (className) {
        ContentFragment::class.java.name -> ContentFragment(inspector)
        else -> super.instantiate(classLoader, className)
    }
}

// Now update your InspectionActivity to implement the interface
// and pass itself into an instance of the FragmentFactory you created
class InspectionActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Inspector {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory =
            InspectionActivityFactory(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...
    }
}
```

`launchFragment` takes a `factory` parameter that allows you to inject a test interface, ensuring that you can check that you get the callbacks you expect without relying on a specific subclass of your activity. When using Kotlin, you can also use the trailing lambda syntax to construct the Fragment and skip manually creating a Factory at all:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun `inspection failure point to location mapping is correct`() {
        val inspector = mock(Inspector::class.java)
        val scenario = launchFragment {
            ContentFragment(inspector)
        }
        scenario.onFragment { fragment ->
            //TODO: test logic
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I've added an example interface, `FragmentFactory`, and how you'd want to change your activity and test to take advantage of them. You'd just want to fill in your interface with whatever methods you need.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example! I decoupled my Activity and Fragment by using interfaces but I opted not to use a Factory. What's the benefit of using a Factory at all? Is it just to make our interface callbacks testable via the launchFragment() method?

Comment: I guess the fragmentfactory method comes in handy when you are not directly instantiating your Fragment e.g viewpager.