# How to test Fragment in isolation using `FragmentScenario` when you have to use parent activity reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm planning to use `FragmentScenario` to test fragments in isolation. In this fragment, I'm accessing parent activity to call some methods. For this, I'm using `CommonActivityOperations` interface. I'm using navigation architecture components in this application.

```
interface CommonActivityOperations {
    fun closeSearchBar()
    fun navigateBackWithResult(resultFor: String, result: Bundle)
}
```

When I'm trying to run the test on my `AttractionDestinationFragment` it gave me the following error.

`java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$EmptyFragmentActivity cannot be cast to .interfaces.CommonActivityOperations`

**AttractionDestinationFragment**

```
const val DESTINATION_DATA_EXTRA = "destination_data_result"

class AttractionDestinationFragment : BaseFragment(), ItemClickListener, ToolbarSearchChangeListener{

    private lateinit var navigationController: NavController
    private lateinit var defaultAttractionList: MutableList<AttractionDestinations>
    private lateinit var attractionDestinationRecyclerViewAdapter: AttractionDestinationRecyclerViewAdapter

    private val viewModel by lazy { getViewModel<AttractionDestinationViewModel>() }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction_destination, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        initialization(view)
        observeAttractionDestinations()
    }

    private fun initialization(view: View) {

        navigationController = Navigation.findNavController(view)

        defaultAttractionList = mutableListOf(...)

        attractionDestinationRecyclerViewAdapter =
                AttractionDestinationRecyclerViewAdapter(defaultAttractionList)
        attractionDestinationRecyclerViewAdapter.itemClickListener = this
        attractionDestinationRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(SimpleLineDividerItemDecoration(context))
        attractionDestinationRecyclerView.adapter = attractionDestinationRecyclerViewAdapter

        activity?.invalidateOptionsMenu()

    }

    private fun observeAttractionDestinations() {

        viewModel.attractionDestinationsLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

            it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.also { resource ->

                when (resource.status) {

                    DataRetrieveStatus.SUCCESS -> {
                        // apply new data
                    }

                    DataRetrieveStatus.RESPONSE_ERROR -> {
                        //Show error
                    }

                    DataRetrieveStatus.CONNECTION_ERROR,
                    DataRetrieveStatus.PROCESSING_ERROR -> {
                        //error handling
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelable(DESTINATION_DATA_EXTRA, attractionDestinationRecyclerViewAdapter.data[position])

        activity?.invalidateOptionsMenu()

        commonActivityOperations.navigateBackWithResult(DESTINATION_DATA_RESULT, bundle)
        commonActivityOperations.closeSearchBar()
    }

    override fun onQueryChange(text: String) {

        if(networkConnectivity.isOnline){

            viewModel.getAttractionDestinations(text)

        }else{
            // Error handling
        }
    }

    override fun onSearchBarClose() {
        // Reset List
    }
```

**BaseFragment**

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var windowFocusChangeReceiver: BroadcastReceiver

    protected var dialogToDisplayOnWindowIsFocus: MaterialDialog.Builder? = null

    lateinit var commonActivityOperations: CommonActivityOperations

    val networkConnectivity: NetworkStatus by lazy { NetworkStatus(context) }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        commonActivityOperations = activity as CommonActivityOperations
        super.onAttach(context)
    }
}
```

**AttractionDestinationFragmentTest**

```
class AttractionDestinationFragmentTest {

    private val mockNavController by lazy {
        Mockito.mock(NavController::class.java)
    }

    @Before
    fun setUp() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        val fragment = AttractionDestinationFragment()

        launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.AppTheme){
            fragment.also { fragment ->
                fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { viewLifecycleOwner ->
                    if (viewLifecycleOwner != null) {
                        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), mockNavController)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Test
    fun destinationRecyclerViewLoadTest(){

        onView(withId(R.id.attractionDestinationRecyclerView))
                .check(RecyclerViewItemCountAssertion(15))
                .perform(actionOnItemAtPosition<AttractionDestinationRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(0, click()))
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
    }
```

As you can see I have set up `CommonActivityOperations` interface inside `onAttach(context: Context)`
in `BaseFragment`. I'm getting this error because `FragmentScenario` creates `EmptyFragmentActivity` which does not implement `CommonActivityOperations` and I'm trying to initiate it.

It there an alternative way to initiate this interface? How to make this fragment testable?

Thanks.

**Edit :**
I have gone through the following similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58651075/fragment-unit-testing-launchfragment-throws-classcastexception).

This question did not resolve the problem I have because I'm using the navigation architecture component. When using navigation architecture component I do not create fragment manually to pass the interface to the fragment like shown in this question.

**AttractionFlowActivity**

```
private fun initialization() {

        navigationController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.hostFragment)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration
                .Builder()
                .setFallbackOnNavigateUpListener(this)
                .build()

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navigationController, appBarConfiguration)

    }
```

The above code shows the initialization function inside the parent activity which is responsible for setting up the navigation architecture component and setting up it with toolbar.

Comment: Navigation uses your `FragmentFactory` to create fragments, so [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58651463/1676363) works perfectly for your case as well.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find a way to use this Interface without referencing activity with navigation architecture components. What I end up doing was using [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/). I created a class that notifies the activity using [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/PublishSubject.html) on value change.

**CommonActivityTrigger**

```
class CommonActivityTrigger private constructor() {

    val navigateBackResultPublishSubject: PublishSubject<Pair<String,Bundle>>
            = PublishSubject.create()
    val closeSearchBarPublishSubject: PublishSubject<Boolean>
            = PublishSubject.create()

    private object HOLDER {
        val INSTANCE = CommonActivityTrigger()
    }

    companion object {
        val INSTANCE: CommonActivityTrigger by lazy { HOLDER.INSTANCE }
    }

    fun navigateBackWithResult(resultFor: String, result: Bundle){
        navigateBackResultPublishSubject.onNext(Pair(resultFor,result))
    }

    fun closeSearchBar(){
        closeSearchBarPublishSubject.onNext(true)
    }
}
```

**AttractionDestinationFragment**

```
class AttractionDestinationFragment : BaseFragment(), ItemClickListener, ToolbarSearchChangeListener{

    private lateinit var defaultAttractionList: MutableList<AttractionDestinations>
    private lateinit var attractionDestinationRecyclerViewAdapter: AttractionDestinationRecyclerViewAdapter

    private val viewModel by lazy { getViewModel<AttractionDestinationViewModel>() }
    private val commonActivityTrigger by lazy { CommonActivityTrigger.INSTANCE }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attraction_destination, container, false)
    }

    override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelable(DESTINATION_DATA_EXTRA, attractionDestinationRecyclerViewAdapter.data[position])

        activity?.invalidateOptionsMenu()

        commonActivityTrigger.navigateBackWithResult(DESTINATION_DATA_RESULT, bundle)
        commonActivityTrigger.closeSearchBar()
    }
}
```

**AttractionFlow1Activity**

```
class AttractionFlow1Activity : AppCompatActivity(), AppBarConfiguration.OnNavigateUpListener {

    private lateinit var navigationController: NavController

    private val navHostFragment by lazy { supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.hostFragment) }
    private val commonActivityTrigger by lazy { CommonActivityTrigger.INSTANCE }

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    private fun navigateBackWithResult() {

        val navigationBlackResultPublishDisposable = commonActivityTrigger
                .navigateBackResultPublishSubject
                .subscribe {

                    val (resultFor, result) = it

                    val childFragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.hostFragment)?.childFragmentManager
                    var backStackListener: FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener by Delegates.notNull()
                    backStackListener = FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {
                        (childFragmentManager?.fragments?.get(0) as NavigationResult).onNavigationResult(resultFor, result)
                        childFragmentManager.removeOnBackStackChangedListener(backStackListener)
                    }
                    childFragmentManager?.addOnBackStackChangedListener(backStackListener)
                    navigationController.popBackStack()
                }

        compositeDisposable.add(navigationBlackResultPublishDisposable)

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        compositeDisposable.dispose()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```